# Robinson annulation

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics

In the mechanism of Robinson annulation, what is the rate determining step?
I have searched in my book but it is not given. If possible please specify the reason for that step being the RDS.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a type of Michael addition. Are you aware of the mechanistic details and RDS of this particular type of addition?

Comment: For an annulation, the ring formation is usually fast given that it's intramolecular. Even if it's not, the reaction is run at high dilution to make it as fast as possible relative to the intermolecular step(s).

Comment: I suspect this would be highly dependent on the reaction conditions and particular substrates being used. Note that all of the steps are reversible.